# C++ sockets acting weird

Tags: c++, windows, sockets

I'm trying to build up a server but the accept() function is acting buggy. Problem is, it accepts empty connections ( I have no clue where they are from ) and it also recives empty things from them.

Here is my Server.cpp class

```
#include "Server.h"
#include <thread>

Server::Server()
{
    usercount = 0;
    int RetVal=0;
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DllVersion=MAKEWORD(2,1);
    RetVal=WSAStartup(DllVersion,&wsaData);
    if( RetVal != 0 )
    {
        MessageBoxA(NULL,"WinSocket startup failed","Error",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR );
        exit(1);
    }
}

bool Server::ServerStartUp()
{
sListen  = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.100");
addr.sin_port        = htons(69);
addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
listen(sListen,64);

//  CreateThread(0,0,&Server::ServerThread,0,0,0);
std::thread t1(&Server::ServerThread,this);
t1.join();

return true;
}

void Server::ServerThread()
{
int addrlen = sizeof(addr); 
for(;;Sleep(10))
{
    if( sConnect = accept( sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, &addrlen )) 
    {
        cout << " FUTU ";
        char* UserName = new char[256];
        ZeroMemory(UserName,256);
        recv(sConnect,UserName,256,0);

        char* Password = new char[256];
        ZeroMemory(Password,256);
        recv(sConnect,Password,256,0);


        users[ ++usercount ] = new Client(UserName,Password,sConnect);

        if( users[usercount] ->GetLogInSuccesful() )
            send(sConnect,"0x0001",6,0);
        else
            send(sConnect,"0x0002",6,0);

    }
}

}
```

I also have a working example with pretty much exactly the same structure, so I have no clue where or what I'm doing wrong...

Working example :

```
int ReturnValue = 0;
ReturnValue = InitWinSocket();

if(ReturnValue != 0)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"WinSocket startup failed","Error",MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR );
    exit(1);
}

users = new User[64];

sListen  = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);
sConnect = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, NULL);

addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.100");
addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;

bind(sListen, (SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(addr));
listen(sListen,64);


int addrlen = sizeof(addr);


for(;;)
{
    if(sConnect = accept(sListen , (SOCKADDR*)&addr,&addrlen))
    {
        int SuccesfulLogIn = 0;
        SuccesfulLogIn = CheckLogInInformation();

        if(SuccesfulLogIn == 0)
        {
            send(sConnect,"0x0002",6,0);
        }
        else
        {

        users[++ConnectionsCounter].UserConnection = sConnect;
        users[ConnectionsCounter].ID = ConnectionsCounter;
        users[ConnectionsCounter].IsUserInGame = false;
        cout<<"Smb Connected";
        send(sConnect,"0x0001",6,0);

        char* Id = new char[20];
        _itoa ( users[ConnectionsCounter].ID,Id,10 );

        send(sConnect,Id,sizeof(Id),0);

        UserThreadHandler[ConnectionsCounter] = CreateThread(0,0,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)UserThread,(LPVOID)ConnectionsCounter,0,0);

        }
    }
}
```

In the second example it only accepts proper connections, and actually waits when it hits the accept() till a connection is found.

I want to know what am I doing wrong.

***Edit due to comment:***

Found out that it is actually my bind function which doesn't work, how can I fix this?

Comment: Please indent the code properly.

Comment: What exactly is the point of starting a new thread and joining it in the very next line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you're trying to listen on a privileged port (one below 1024), on an OS that doesn't allow the user you're running the program as to do that. bind(), listen(), accept(), etc. return values indicating success or failure -- you should NEVER call them without checking those return values.

Comment: Thnx to you I found out that the bind function doesn't work, I also changed the port to 1234. Any clue what's wrong with my bind function?

Comment: As I said, you were binding to a low-numbered port. On UNIX, only root can do that. On Windows, I'm sure there's similar limitations.

Comment: Managed to get it right by editing the ip address to addr.sin_addr.s_addr = ADDR_ANY; Since it was your answer that made me realise bind wasn't working you get my +1 ;)